# How to create a Graphics object to draw shapes on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

I want to make a program to animate a projectile (a ball flying in a projectile in 2D). In main I call a Shoot() function whose argument is a Graphics object, but I don't know how to create the object so that it draws on my JFrame object. Please help me.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Projectile extends JPanel{
    public static int ScreenH=1500;
    public static int ScreenW=3000;
    public static int Xcor=0;
    public static int Ycor=0;
    public static int ballRadius=20;
    public static int prevXcor = 0;
    public static int prevYcor = 0;
    public static int newXcor = 0;
    public static int newYcor = 0;
    public static int Time = 0;
    public static int Angle = 45;
    public static int Velocity = 10;
    public static double Acceleration = 9.8;

    public static void InitGraphics(){
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setTitle("Projectile");
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setSize(ScreenW, ScreenH);
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.add(new Projectile());
    }

    public static void drawCenteredCircle(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
          int a = x;
          int b = 1000 - y;
          g.fillOval(a,b, ballRadius, ballRadius);
        }

    public static void move() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(20);
        Time += 20;
        double XVelocity = Math.sin(Velocity);
        double YVelocity = Math.cos(Velocity);
        int X = (int) (XVelocity*Time);
        int Y = (int) ((YVelocity*Time) + (0.5*Acceleration*Time*Time));
        newXcor = X;
        newYcor = Y;
    }

    public static void repaint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        drawCenteredCircle(g, prevXcor, prevYcor);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        drawCenteredCircle(g, newXcor, newYcor);

        prevXcor = newXcor;
        prevYcor = newYcor;
    }

    public static void Shoot(Graphics g) throws InterruptedException {
        while ( (newXcor < (ScreenW - (4*ballRadius))) && (newYcor < (ScreenH - (4*ballRadius)))) {
            move();
            repaint(g);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[]args) {
        InitGraphics();
        Shoot();
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `public static void repaint(Graphics g)` with `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`, remove the `Graphics g` parameter from the `Shoot` method and call `repaint()` instead of `repaint(g)`.

Comment: How can I call repaint() if I replace repaint() with paintComponent? repaint() wouldnt be defined then.

Comment: Your class extends `JPanel` and `JPanel` has a `repaint()` method which   will call `paintComponent(...)` at some point passing it this panel's `Graphics` object.

Comment: It says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method repaint() from the type component", when I bring my cursor over the repaint() call in Shoot().

Comment: You can make all your methods non-static or create a static reference to the `Projectile` instance that you add to the frame and call `replaint()` on that.

Comment: `public static void Shoot(Graphics g) throws InterruptedException {
        while ( (newXcor < (ScreenW - (4*ballRadius))) && (newYcor < (ScreenH - (4*ballRadius)))) {
            move();
            repaint(g);
        }
    }` It will be necessary to remove the loop and instead trigger `repaint()` from use of a Swing `Timer`.  OTOH a combination of GUIs, custom painting and animation is wicked difficult. It looks like you are a newbie, so I suspect that you've bitten off more than you can chew for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The JFrame is just the window, you need to add a JComponent to it. JComponents contain a `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method which you need to override like this:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JComponent canvas = new JComponent() {
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            //call repaint(g) here instead of this
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        };
    };
    frame.add(canvas);
```

You will probably have to clear the background in repaint

Comment: I see. And what argument of type 'Graphics' should I give shoot()?

Comment: It depends on your design. What does shoot do? Shoot a graphics? paintComponent will be called by the system and you can pass the Graphics Object g to shoot

Comment: And call `super.paintComponent`